# How to fill in missing NAN's?

Tags: matlab, if-statement, conditional-statements, user-defined-functions, nan

I want to change `[1 nan 1 2 2 nan nan 3 nan 4 nan nan 5]` into `[1 1.5 1 2 2 2 3 3 3.5 4 4 5 5]`.  If there is a single NAN, I want the NAN to be filled in with the average of the numbers before and after.  If there is more than one NAN.
 I want the NAN to be filled in with the nearest number.

So far, I only have the code to find the single NAN's:

```
max_x = x(:, 2);
min_x = x(:, 3);

for jj = 1:length(max_x)
    for kk = 1:length(min_x)
        if isnan(max_x(jj))
            max_x (jj) = ((max_x(jj-1)+max_x(jj+1))/2);
        elseif isnan (min_x(kk))
            min_x (kk) = ((min_x(kk-1)+min_x(kk+1))/2);
        end
    end
end
```

How do I fill in the NAN's that aren't single?

Much thanks.

Comment: can there be more than 2 NAN between the values? If so what happens for example with [2 nan nan nan 3]? Is it [2 2 2 3 3] or [2 2 3 3 3]?

Comment: Is there a little error in your example at the first nan? 1.5 is not the average of 1 and 1

Comment: I don't understand how the first `NaN` becomes `1.5` when it's between two `1`s? Is this a typo? It's not what your code would output.

Comment: Oh yes I made a typo, it's supposed to be [ 1 nan 2 2 2 nan nan 3 nan 4 nan nan 5], so the average between 1 and 2 would be 1.5

Comment: Yes there can be more than 2 NAN between values and it can range up to more than 10 NANs in a row.  If so what happens with [2 nan nan nan 3] is that it becomes either [2 2 2.5 3 3]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The title of this question is also nearly the answer - Fill in missing values using [`fillmissing`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fillmissing.html).

```
A = [1 nan 1 2 2 nan nan 3 nan 4 nan nan 5];
B = fillmissing(A,'linear');
```

This function was introduced in R2016b.

---

The same logic can be implemented using `interp1` and `isnan`.

```
idx = ~isnan( A );
x = 1:numel(A);
B = interp1( x(idx), A(idx), x, 'linear', 'extrap' );
```

Note that the extrapolation here gives slightly different behaviour for `NaN` values at each end of the input vectors.

Answer (score 0):

A sample code:

```
% To paste in main .m file
A = [1 nan 1 2 2 nan nan 3 nan 4 nan nan 5]; % Input array
[A] = new_array(A)                           % Function to get a new array

% To paste in individual .m file as function
function [x]= new_array(x)
is_nan_ar = isnan(x); % Getting 0/1 array of nan elements
array_l = length(x);  % Getting length of x array (just to do it only once)
for k = 1:array_l % Checking every element of input array whether it's...
    if (k==1) && (is_nan_ar(k)==1) % First element and nan
        kk = 2; % Initial index for searching the nearest non-nan element
        while (isnan(is_nan_ar(kk))==1) % Checking elements for being nan
            kk=kk+1;  % Increasing index while we're searching
        end
        x(k) = x(kk); % Writing down the first not nan element
    elseif (k==array_l) && (is_nan_ar(k)==1) % The same search for the last
        kk = array_l-1; % Intial index
        while (isnan(is_nan_ar(kk))==1) % Reversed search for not not nan
            kk=kk-1;
        end
        x(k) = x(kk); % Writing down what we found
    elseif (is_nan_ar(k)==1) % When we're checking not the first and not the last
        s_r = 1; % Search range (1 element to the left/right)
        while (is_nan_ar(k-s_r)==1) && (is_nan_ar(k+s_r)==1) %Looking for not nan
            s_r = s_r+1; % Increasment of the range if didn't find
        end
        if (is_nan_ar(k-s_r)==0) && (is_nan_ar(k+s_r)==0) % Two non-nans are near
            x(k) = (x(k-s_r)+x(k+s_r))/2;
        elseif (is_nan_ar(k-s_r)==0) % Only one non-nan on the left
            x(k) = x(k-s_r);
        else % Only one non-nan on the right
            x(k) = x(k+s_r);
        end
    end
end
end
```